# How to disable a default user install for python pip?

Tags: python, pip

My computer was preconfigured to add the `--user` flag to pip installs by default via the pip.ini config file. This does not appear to be compatible with virtual environments. Is there a pip command line flag to set user=false?

Comment: And what system is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually yes, you can use `--no-user` flag which have (or at least should) higher priority than the one configured in .ini file.

Another thing is probably it's configured on some global space you do not have access to, but it should be possible to have your local **pip.ini** file that has precedence over global one.

As last resort, you can use `python -m pip install` in virtual env, it should corectly install things in virtualenv.

Comment: That worked! It would be nice if it was documented in the pypa docs